# Alarmmanager fires first time but doesn't repeat

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want an Alarmmanager to fire first time after 2 Seconds and then every 10 Sec.

It doesn't fire the first time exactly 2 seconds later. Something between 5 and 10 sec later. And it doesn't repeat at all.

Here is my Code:

Alarmmanager:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
final PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2 * 1000, 10 * 1000, pendingintent);
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".BackgroundService"/>
```

BackgroundService.java:

```
public class BackgroundService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("BackgroundService", "BackgroundService onReceive");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try not to use AlarmManager Class.

Comment: what else? and why not?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);

Comment: This sets the Alarm Actually. AlarmManager calls this method inside it. So, its better to access it using Intents.

Comment: okay, and where do i tell him which class is the receiver?

Comment: You do not need a BroadcastReceiver for it. You carry on with your flow of work. That would also be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it:

The IDE says: The 3rd value will be forced up to 60000 (1 Min) to save battery. But I never waited so long, so it looked like it doesn't even repeates.

[Snap is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O83BB.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, **cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis()**, 1000*60*5 , pendingIntent);
```

I think you are using System.currentTimeMillis() because of which you are having that issue. Try to get the time from you code for which you have set the Alarm. The third parameter in the above code is the repeating time. You can set it to 10 sec.

Comment: i changed it to: `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 2);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 2000, pendingintent);`
Same result

Comment: Date dat = new Date();
    Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_now.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Comment: I meant your time which you are setting for the alarm, since you want the Alarm to be set for let's say morning, 5:30 A.M. Set the cal_alarm to that value.

Comment: yeah, isn't that what i'm doing?
i add 2 seconds to the currant time - calender.add(Calender.Second, 2)
and use this as 2nd parameter

Comment: Did, you get current date using Date? What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Date gives me the current Date. But Calendar says: ....MONTH=9.... Shouldn't it be MONTH=10?

Answer (score 0):

this heslp me

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            } else {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }
```